# selenium python create a if statement and break if the if statement is found

Tags: python, selenium, if-statement, automation

so am trying to implement a `if` statement when an element `limit` is found must click and break or else continue with the loop

my code below

```
all_buttons = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("button")
    connect_buttons = [btn for btn in all_buttons if btn.text == "Connect" ]
    for btn in connect_buttons:
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", btn)
        time.sleep(2)
        send = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@aria-label='Send now']")
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", send)
        time.sleep(2)
        limit = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@aria-label='Got it']")
        if limit.is_displayed:
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",limit)
            print("limit reached")
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `try - except` instead of `if - else`:

```
all_buttons = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("button")
    connect_buttons = [btn for btn in all_buttons if btn.text == "Connect" ]
    for btn in connect_buttons:
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", btn)
        time.sleep(2)
        send = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@aria-label='Send now']")
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", send)
        time.sleep(2)
        flag = True
        while flag:
            try:
                limit = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@aria-label='Got it']")
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",limit)
                print("limit reached")
                flag = False
            except:
                flag = True
```

Comment: i tried your code. i want it after find the `limit` variable it must stop if not continue with the loop and with try is not breaking after it finds `limit` variable

Comment: Try it with `while`. Updated

Comment: I don't understand you correctly but I think that is what you wanted